# Powershell - How to Give Full Access a List of Local User for Folders

Tags: powershell, permissions, directory, acl

I have a CSV file that containts a Folder Name (first 6 characters) and a User Name (rest of characters).
I have to give Full Control Access to each User in His Folder. So I wrote the:

```
$Doc = import-csv "C:\Temp\ListOfUsers.csv"

foreach ($x in $Doc)
  {

     $x = ""+ $x

     $CPayID = $x.SubString(10,6)

     $UserName = $x.SubString(17, $x.Length-18)

     $UserPath = "C:\XPAY_FTP_CUST\"+$CPayID

     $Acl = Get-Acl $UserPath

     $Rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("$Username","FullControl","ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit","None","Allow")

     $Acl.SetAccessRule($Rule)

     Set-Acl $UserPath $Acl
  }
```

But I received the following Error for Each User:

> Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity references could not be translated."

The Users exist and are locals, I am local administrator, and when I ask for echo the `$Username`, the `$UserPath`, and the `$Acl` I receive correct data.
Please, I need any help.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to specify the username as `DOMAIN\user`. In case of local users, `DOMAIN` will be the computer name:

```
$UserReference = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount $env:ComputerName,$Username
$Rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($UserReference,"FullControl","ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit","None","Allow")
```

Answer (score -1):

Mathias is much, much smarter than I am at this, but I noticed this in your code:
`($UserReference,"FullControl","ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit","None","Allow")`

Should `"ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit"` instead be `"ContainerInherit", "ObjectInherit"`?